# How to keep track of online users in GraphQL using GraphQL-Java-Kickstart

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

Currently I am using `ApolloSubscriptionConnectionListener`.

It contains 4 methods: `onConnect`, `onTerminate`, `onStart` and `onStop`.

However `onTerminate` did not fire when I close my client. `onStop` seems to fire every time the client canceled the subscription. How can I check that a user is online?